# React: how ot render a url?

Tags: reactjs, url, syntax

This may sound simple but I can't make it works.
I have this url to an item in a sharepoint list:

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/Demo2/Lists/AgreementDatabase/DispForm.aspx?ID=1
```

and I want to render it using react but the ID part is not working:

```
render: (item: IList) => {
    return (<a href="https://hernancompany.sharepoint.com/sites/Demo2/Lists/AgreementDatabase/DispForm.aspx?ID=${item.Id}">{item.Title}</a>);
  }
```

instead for **ID=1** it renders **ID=${item.Id}** 
Which is the correct syntax for this?

EDIT: 
You mean like this?:

Do you mean like this:

```
return (<a href=`https://hernancompany.sharepoint.com/sites/Demo2/Lists/AgreementDatabase/DispForm.aspx?ID=${item.Id}`>{item.Title}</a>);
```

because that didn't worked.

Best regards
Americo

Comment: You can write code in the comments by using backticks \`code goes here\` produces `code goes here`.

Comment: Fix your edit to have a curly brace in front of the initial backtick and after the last backtick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use the backtick method: { `url/path/goes/here${ variableCanGoHere }`}

```
render: (item: IList) => {
    return (<a href={`https://hernancompany.sharepoint.com/sites/Demo2/Lists/AgreementDatabase/DispForm.aspx?ID=${item.Id}`}>{item.Title}</a>);
  }
```

Comment: FWIW, the backticks denote a [**template literal**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score -1):

Try using backticks (backtics?) near the Esc button on your computer.

```
`https://hernancompany.sharepoint.com/sites/Demo2/Lists/AgreementDatabase/DispForm.aspx?ID=${item.Id}`
```

Backtics are what would make this work.  This is a newer feature I believe.

Comment: I have updated the post, I can't write code in the comments.

Comment: Template literals (the backticks) have been introduced in ES2015 (ES6).